# Unable to connect to Linux (Virtual OS-vmware) through Putty on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty

I want to access my Linux box (Virtual OS) through Putty on Windows using Run command:

```
putty -ssh -P 22 192.168.171.130,,,
```

but it is returning an error message, not able to connect.

But few days back I was able to connect it today. But not now. Why??

```
Windows IP Configuration

        Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : rba7791fd466
        Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
        Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
        IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for
VMnet1
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.234.1
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Dell Wireless 1395 WLAN Mini-Card
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-24-2B-60-A0-88
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.2
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
        Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, August 28, 2009 4:11:09 AM
        Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, August 29, 2009 4:11:09 AM
```

> ```
> Ubuntu Configuration
> eth0 inet addr:192.168.171.130
> ```

Comment: It probably just got another IP-adress this time. Your client should ask by DHCP, but vmware will give you a NAT-compliant ip-number.

Comment: can you ping it?  is ssh server running on ubuntu? on port 22?

Comment: how can i check that,, whether ssh server is running on port 22 or not,, or if it is not working, then how to work it on..

Comment: Are you sure you bridged the network and the virtual network is not NATed?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the ssh server is actually running inside Ubuntu.

try  # ps aux | grep ssh

or # netstat -anp | grep ssh

Comment: good call...gotta be running ssh server before connecting to it...I had this happen to me.   I thought it was installed by default.

Comment: unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8408     -                   /tmp/ssh-ltHduf3078/agent.3078
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8959     3065/gnome-keyring- /tmp/keyring-ej2gKw/socket.ssh

Comment: This is the output of netstat,, please help sir..

Comment: as root
 # aptitude install openssh-server
and then 
 netstat -anp | grep ssh

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to ping it?  Did you change anything else on your windows system or Linux Virtual box?  Have you verified that a firewall isn't blocking it?  Have you tried opening up the putty GUI in windows and connecting that way?

There are many potential answers, the more information you can provide the better we can solve your problem.

Comment: I have switched the firewall off, then also it is not working..
not able to ping guest os's IP from windows host os

Answer (score 0):

You've determined that you can't find the guest over the network with one service; can you ping the computer from the host to the guest?

It looks like you also have a windows host on the 10.x network while the VMWare system is on the 192.x network. You might want to reconfigure it so that it's a bridged network connection instead of NAT, as I've seen weird issues with NAT connections in VMs especially if you double-nat a connection to the real network. But that's another issue.

I don't know if VMWare is one of the VM systems that also has trouble with host wireless networking also. Did this previously work while on a wired connection but not wireless, or did it work before with wireless too?

Does your guest have network access?

Can your guest ping or connect to the host over the network?

Are you certain that you don't have any firewall software running on the host/guest that will block access?

Is SSH up and running? Can the guest ssh into itself?

What does netstat in the guest Linux machine tell you is monitoring various ports?

Anything in the logs on the guest?

Comment: I am not able to ping guest machine. from windows..

Comment: I am using both OS's on same machine... It was working for me few days back, but it is not working now.. dont know why..

Comment: I have switched the firewall off, but then also it is not working..

Comment: I donot find any information on port 22 by executing netstat on guest os

Comment: If you can't find anything listening on port 22 (sshd) and you haven't changed anything from defaults, then it's not running sshd. That's why you can't ssh from the host into the guest (or in part that's the reason). What happens if you run sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart (or sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a networking issue to me. Your VM seems to be on a different subnet than your bridge. That may cause problems if your network is routing elsewhere. Check your routes to make sure that it can actually connect.